# "INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" stops at check constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing my test task. I started building a schema. I'm not good at all with creating tables, modifying tables. At work I used to do only queries to DB and make some layouts to display data. So, I picked PostgreSQL at [www.db-fiddle.com](http://www.db-fiddle.com) and start building a schema.

```
create table users (
);

alter table users
add nm varchar(999) not null,
add skype varchar(999);

alter table users
add constraint unique_skyp unique(skype);
alter table users
add constraint chk_skyp_form check(skype ~* '^skype:([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*){6,32}');

insert into users(nm, skype)
values ('Yaroslaw','skyp') 
on conflict do nothing;
```

My intention is to prevent database user to insert skype login that has an inappropriate form. To test that, I wrote some inserts. I hoped that insert will ignore an error if one pops up. What I got is this:

```
Schema Error: error: new row for relation "users" violates check constraint "chk_skyp_form"
```

What I want is to have bunch of inserts run without interruption. But I get the above message. How can I fix this?

Comment: `on conflict do nothing` works for unique, primary key and exclusion constraints. A check constraint is none of those.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  What type of constraint better suits my situation?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What I want is somehow to pass through check constraint.

Comment: If your intention is to prevent database users from inserting the wrong thing, it seems like this error would do that.

Comment: @Jeremy My intention is to write some unit tests on my schema. I will write some inserts and some of them should not fit into database. What I want is to have multiple insert commands executed without being interrupted by error message. Later on, I will do queries to database to determine the tests that failed.

Comment: There is nothing for that, you'll need to change how you test.